# How to add youtube player in a modal bottom sheet flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, youtube

I am using [youtube_player_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter) in a project, I need to implement this in a modal bottom sheet. How can I implement this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) => Scaffold(
    body: YoutubePlayer(…),
  ),
),
```